# TweetInvi does not retrieve tweet's picture

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

I'm reading tweets using the following code, it works fine but the media object is always empty even if the tweet has a picture but it works fine if the tweet has a video instead of picture!

```
            var stream = userClient.Streams.CreateFilteredStream();
            stream.TweetMode = Tweetinvi.TweetMode.Extended;
            var twitterUser = await userClient.Users.GetUserAsync(username);
            stream.AddFollow(twitterUser);
            stream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, eventReceived) =>
            {
                
                if(!eventReceived.Tweet.Retweeted)
                    Console.WriteLine(eventReceived.Tweet);
            };

            await stream.StartMatchingAllConditionsAsync();
```

I was debugging every tweets and verify that each one has a picture in twitter website.

[image: This is the media object]

Comment: What is the media object for you? 0 items? I am able to get this to work without issues, the only difference being I used `stream.AddTrack(string)` instead.

Comment: @TimothyG. It's empty when the tweet has a picture, if the tweet has a video it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Media` member of `ITweet` is a `List<IMediaEntity>`.  It's possible for this list to be empty.  Using the below code, I was able to receive tweets with their `Media` member containing [`IMediaEntity`](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/blob/91cdf83b87f6c0c75d7ece6a13fce792d820e3c8/src/Tweetinvi.Core/Public/Models/Entities/IMediaEntity.cs) objects:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task = Task.Run(() => BeginTweetStream());
    await task;
}

public static async Task BeginTweetStream()
{
    string userName = "SomeName";
    int i = 0;
    TwitterClient userClient = new TwitterClient("string", "string", "string", "string"); //where the strings are credentials
    var stream = userClient.Streams.CreateFilteredStream();
    stream.TweetMode = Tweetinvi.TweetMode.Extended;
    var twitterUser = await userClient.Users.GetUserAsync(userName);
    stream.AddTrack("SomeTrack");
    stream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, eventReceived) =>
    {
        if (eventReceived.Tweet.Media != null && eventReceived.Tweet.Media.Any() && !eventReceived.Tweet.Retweeted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Tweet with {eventReceived.Tweet.Media.Count()} media found!");

            foreach (Tweetinvi.Models.Entities.IMediaEntity media in eventReceived.Tweet.Media)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Media type: {media.MediaType} Link: {media.URL}");
            }

            ++i;
        }

        if (i == 99) //stop after 100 tweets with media
        {
            stream.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Complete! Press any key to exit.");
            Console.Read(); 
        }
    };

    await stream.StartMatchingAllConditionsAsync();
}
```

Console Output:

[image: Output]

You can check the `IMediaEntity.MediaType` member to see what kind of media it is.  I haven't been able to find documentation of what values this can be set to, but so far, I've seen:

- `photo`
- `video`
- `animated_gif`

Note that the `URL` member of the `IMediaEntity` object is the link to the tweet itself.  If you are after the picture itself, `MediaURL` or `MediaURLHttps` will contain the link to only the picture (for videos and animated GIFs, these members are the link to the thumbnail picture instead).

Comment: I used your code exactly but I used "Khaberni" for AddTrack instead of "SomeTrack" I got the tweets but without their pictures!

Comment: @Cassini I'm at a loss.  So you aren't getting any links in the `IMediaEntity.MedialURL` for example?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any link.

Comment: @Cassini Can you post screenshots of your empty media object and tweet objects?

Comment: I added the screenshot to the question.

Comment: @Cassini I looked up the tweet using the ID in the screenshot, and it does not contain an image, but rather a [link to a website article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMf5D.png) that Twitter renders with a thumbnail, but that isn't technically a photo, at least not in the sense that it gets returned as part of the array of `IMediaEntity`.  Here is a tweet from that account that **does** contain an image: https://twitter.com/khaberni/status/1396480461447249925 - [and Tweetinvi indicates this too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ard0R.png)

Comment: In other words, I think you've been examining tweets that you thought contained photos, but really they just contain a link to a news article/external website where Twitter renders a image from the new article itself into the thumbnail. And looking at what Tweetinvi provides, you can't get that photo out of the tweet.

Comment: Here is an example of the tweet that I was reading https://twitter.com/khaberni/status/1396519075111739396 is that image is not a part of this tweet!

Comment: @Cassini Again, that is not a "photo" in the tweet, not in the sense that it will be in the Media entity array.  That is a thumbnail to a *link* that twitter renders, and the Twitter API does not provide those images back to users.  In my previous comment, I [linked](https://twitter.com/khaberni/status/1396480461447249925) to a tweet that contains an actual photo that does get returned by the API.  Your code as well as mine works, but the tweets you are looking at do not contain photos that are returned as part of the `IMediaEntity` array, hence why it has 0 items.